# Use parameter in PowerShell in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, dynamics-365

We have recently started using Azure DevOps Pipelines for our Dynamics 365 CRM implementation, but it is still new to me

I recently came across [this](https://crmchap.co.uk/migrating-microsoft-dataverse-access-team-templates-via-azure-devops/) blog post by Joe Griffin on how you can use PowerShell in Azure DevOps pipelines to ensure, that Access Team Templates works when deploying a solution - and I would like to use that.

However, I don't know where I add my parameters to script. Can I do that inline or do I need to add the script to my repo to do that? If so - how can I do that?

```
param(
    #objectTypeCode: Unique Code that identifies the table in the environment for the Access Team Template. Always potentially different.
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [int]$objectTypeCode,
    #atName: Name of the Access Team Template
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$atName,
    #accessRights: Number which represents the access rights defined for the template. Refer to this article for details on how to construct: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/accessrights?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [int]$accessRights,
    #d365URL: URL of the environment to connect to
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$d365URL,
    #clientID: AAD Client ID for the Application User linked to this environment
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$clientID,
    #clientSecret: AAD Client Secret for the Application User linked to this environment
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$clientSecret
)

#Install dependencies
Install-Module Microsoft.Xrm.Data.PowerShell -Scope CurrentUser -Force
#Connect to the D365 environment
$conn = Connect-CrmOnline -ServerUrl $d365URL -ClientSecret $clientSecret -OAuthClientId $clientID -OAuthRedirectUri "http://localhost"
#We first attempt to retrieve the rows if they already exist, and update it accordingly; if this errors, then the row does not exist, so we need to create it instead
Write-Host "Processing Access Team Template for $atName..."
try
{
    $atTemplate = Get-CrmRecord -conn $conn -EntityLogicalName teamtemplate -Id "44396647-CEDF-EB11-BACB-000D3A5810F2" -Fields teamtemplateid,teamtemplatename,objecttypecode,defaultaccessrightsmask,issystem
    $atTemplateId = $atTemplate.teamtemplateid
    Write-Host "Got existing Access Team Template row with ID $atTemplateId!"
    $atTemplate.teamtemplatename = $atName
    $atTemplate.objecttypecode = $objectTypeCode
    $atTemplate.defaultaccessrightsmask = $accessRights
    $atTemplate.issystem = 0
    Set-CrmRecord -conn $conn -CrmRecord $atTemplate
    Write-Host "Successfully updated Access Team Template row with ID $atTemplateId!"
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException]
{
    Write-Host "Access Template row with ID $atTemplateId does not exist, creating..."
    $atTemplateId = New-CrmRecord -conn $conn -EntityLogicalName teamtemplate `
    -Fields @{"teamtemplateid"=[guid]"{44396647-CEDF-EB11-BACB-000D3A5810F2}";"teamtemplatename"=$atName;"objecttypecode"=$objectTypeCode;"defaultaccessrightsmask"=$accessRights;"issystem"=0}   
    Write-Host "Successfully created new Access Template row with ID $atTemplateId"
}
Write-Host "Script execution finished!"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "Azure Powershell" task (If the script has to do something on azure) and can specify path to your powershell file and can add parameter values as in this screenshot,

[image]

or you can use "Powershell"task and can add path to the file and parameter,

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can add a Powershell task in your yaml and invoke the Powershell script to perform required task. Script arguments can be set in and passed through DevOps library.

```
    - task: AzurePowerShell@5
      displayName: 'Powershell task'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.ServiceConn }}'
        ScriptType: 'FilePath'
        ScriptPath: '[Path to script]/PowershellScriptName.ps1'
        ScriptArguments: '-objectTypeCode $(objectTypeCode) -atName $(atName) -accessRights $(accessRights) -d365URL $(d365URL) -clientID $(clientID) -clientSecret $(clientSecret)'
        azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
        pwsh: true
```